# Clarification on this equation defining Inertia tensor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Goldstein pg 194

> The inertia tensor is defined in general from the kinetic energy or rotation about an axis, and is written as
> $$
> T_{\text {rotation }}=\frac{1}{2} m_{i}\left(\omega \times \mathbf{r}_{i}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{2} \omega_{\alpha} \omega_{\beta} m_{i}\left(\delta_{\alpha \beta} r_{i}^{2}-r_{i \alpha} r_{i \beta}\right) \text {, }
> $$
> where Greek letters indicate the components of $\omega$ and $\mathbf{r}_{i}$. In an inertial frame, the sum is over the particles in the body, and $r_{i \alpha}$ is the $\alpha$ th component of the position of the $i$ th particle. Because $T_{\text {rotation }}$ is a bilinear form in the components of $\omega$, it can be written as
> $$
> T_{\text {rotation }}=\frac{1}{2} I_{\alpha \beta} \omega_{\alpha} \omega_{\beta}
> $$

I'm not able to understand how ,$$T= \frac{1}{2} \omega_{\alpha} \omega_{\beta} m_{i}\left(\delta_{\alpha \beta} r_{i}^{2}-r_{i \alpha} r_{i \beta}\right) \text {, }
$$ why don't the third components  $\omega_{\gamma}$ and $r_{\gamma}$ enter the equation?

Comment: All components enter the equation! Try to write down the component of the inertia tensor when $\alpha = 1$, $\beta = 1$. For any given pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ you can calculate this component. So every index $\alpha$ and $\beta$ works in this equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account the following and knowing that the repeated indices are implicitly summed over:
\begin{equation}
    |\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r_i}|^2 = e_{k \alpha m}\omega_{\alpha}r_{im}e_{k \beta n} \omega_{\beta} r_{in}
 \end{equation}
Knowing that Levi- Cevita symbol contraction from an equation with Kroneker symbol

\begin{equation}
e_{k \alpha m}e_{k \beta n} = \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta_{mn}- \delta_{m \beta} \delta_{\alpha n} 
\end{equation}

Then by applying everything you get the formula in question

Comment: Are you sure about the first equation?

Comment: Thanks, @Nashmiri, effectively,I forgot. Check the correction.  There is a power to the first equation

Comment: Great. It's clear now. :)

Comment: Cool, happy to help, thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you seem to think that the components of $\mathbf{r}$ are labelled by Greek letters, such that $\mathbf{r} = (r_{\alpha},r_{\beta},r_{\gamma})$, making $\gamma$ the third component. This is, however, not what is meant here.

Could it be that you are unfamiliar with Einstein's summation convention? The $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not supposed to be definite component labels but summation indices running over all components. The Einstein summation convention basically says that if an index appears twice in an expression, it is to be summed over. Let us say that they run from $1$ to $3$, where $1,2,3$ are the labels on $\mathbf{r} = (r_1,r_2,r_3)$ and $\mathbf{\omega} = (\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)$. Then your expression is
$$ T = \frac{1}{2}m_i \sum_{\alpha=1}^3 \sum_{\beta = 1}^3 \omega_{\alpha}\omega_{\beta} (\delta_{\alpha\beta}r_i^2 - r_{i\alpha} r_{i\beta}).$$
You can perform the full sum, then you see that all components of $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{\omega}$ enter the expression equally. The Einstein summation convention just saves you the hassle of writing sums all the time.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you